# Can I use the word "hacker" as an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, attributive-nouns

Can I use the noun *hacker* as an adjective?

For example, can I write or say:

> It was a hacker trick.

so that it means this:

> It was a trick of a hacker.

And can I use

> It's hacker code.

so that it means this:

> The code has been created by a hacker.

Comment: Any noun may be used attributively (as an adjective). A shop window; a bathroom door; a cheese sandwich...

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross What about the examples? Does it set the teeth on edge?

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross I mean does it stay possessive for a 'hacker'? A hacker's word - a word of a hacker?

Comment: I think it very much depends on where you intend to use it.

Comment: "It was a hacker trick" and "It's hacker code" both sound fine to me.

Comment: You might find a difference in meaning between "a hacker's word" and "a hacker word" ... but both sound fine to me also.

Comment: Do you mean hacker as in criminal, or do you mean hacker as in expert coder engaged in recreational programming? Also, just because you have two nouns in a row does not mean that the first one has become an adjective.  For example, windshield wipe does not have *windshield* as an adjective, because you cannot say *windshielder* for "more windshield" or *windshieldest* for "most wildshield".

Comment: @tchrist I mean **hacker** as an expert of code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both "hacker trick" and "hacker code" are acceptable. Technically, the word doesn't become an adjective. English nouns can act as modifiers (called attributive nouns or [noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)). For more information, check out [this tutorial](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using "*hack*" instead of "*trick of a hacker*" or a "*hacker trick*" as the word [hack](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hack) in itself would mean that it is a patch or a clever workaround(*in other words a trick*).

> It was a hack.

And to indicate that its a "*hacker's code*", use

> Its hacky code.

instead.

From [Wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hacky)

**Hacky** : *Using, or characterised by, hacks*

Comment: And what if I would like to distinguish humanity? E.g. is 'a hacker school' more preferable than 'a hacky school' (as a school of hackers)?

Comment: In this particular context, "_XYZ is a hack school_".

Comment: Is it acceptable enough to say 'a hacker school' and 'a hack school'? Is the 'hack school' definitely better or they are equivalent?

Comment: I wouldn't go that far to suggest that "_hack school_" is **definitely** better than "_a hacker school_" but certainly they are more or less equivalent and their usage would be dictated by the context they are placed in.

Comment: 'A hack school' means the school where people study to hack and 'A hacker school' means the school with hackers (probably people study to hack too). Am I right?

Comment: `school with hackers`? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Actually I mean that the school is a community of hackers.

Comment: As in a "school of fish"? Now that seems a bit awkward. Don't give such collective names on your own.

Comment: -1. There is a vast difference between a hack (something not quite ideal being used as a workaround for something) and a hacker(’s) trick (a common exploit that hackers take advantage of to gain access to a mainframe, for example). ‘Hacky’ also does not work, since it refers to something that uses hacks, rather than something that is characterised by hackers. Code-hacking is not simply using hacks, it is an entirely different kettle of fish. If there were such a thing as a school where hackers were taught, I’d call it a hacking school or a hacker school—never a hack school.

Answer (score 0):

I work in cyber and have never heard of *hacky*. It sounds unprofessional and on the level of "script kiddies".

I like *hacker trick* or *hacker code*.

Comment: This shouldn't be posted as an answer. It's a response to the answer by @KeyBrd Basher.  Add it as a comment to that answer.